# How do Index an Array of type IEnumerable<Data Row>?

Tags: c#

I want to index an Array of `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and print out the Data into a table. I get the below error and I'm not sure hoe to overcome it.

> cannot convert type `System.Data.DataRow` to `string`

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from result in 
                      DtSet.Tables["Results"].AsEnumerable()
                      where result.Field<string 
                      ("test").Contains("50")
                      select result;


var queryArray = query.ToArray();`

for (int i = 0; i < queryArray.Count(); i++)
            {
                table.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(queryArray[i]);
            }
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<DataRow> queryArray = ` -> `DataRow[] queryArray = `? You're currently materialising an `IEnumerable` with `.ToArray()`, but assigning it to an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @John My fault, that was a typo.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do in that llinq statement. Append is used to add an item to a collection. `Paragraphs.First()` is a single `Paragraph` which I assume is a collection of strings. `queryArray` is an array of `DataRow`, so `queryArray[i]` is a single `DataRow`. Did you mean to access a particular item from that `DataRow` or do you want to concatenate them all into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
var queryArray = query.ToArray();
```

(You also have a small problem in that you're trying to stuff a datarow into your destination paragraph; this might just append "system.data.datarow" to your paragraph)

But really you could just delete that line and:

```
int i = 1:
foreach(var q in query)           
  table.Rows[i++].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(q["your column name"].ToString());
```

That is to say; enumerate the IEnumerable, using a separate indexer variable to keep track of where you are in (the excel sheet?)

Side note; I put a call into extract a single column from the data row; you could alternatively make this a part of your select LINQ statement, converting the datarow to a string enuneabke instead

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using a dataview rowfilter might save you some effort here, something like:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(DtSet.Tables["Results"]);
dv.RowFilter = "test LIKE '%50%'";

foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
{
    //do the stuff...
}
```

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.8)